# Combine multiple classes with multiple animations

Tags: css, stylesheet, css-animations

The situation I would like to create is as following:
- Have a css file with several (lets say 10) animations ready like fadein, fadeout, roll-left, roll-right etc.
- Create an div element with class=’fadein roll-left’ I want this element to fadein and roll-left.

I want this to be accomplished without creating a .fadein.roll-left class because when I’ve got 10 animations I need to make (something like?) 10^10 classes to be able to get all the variations?

Here is a codepen for better explanation: http://codepen.io/Sormano/pen/Bbphs

In short my question is: is there any way to ‘merge’ multiple animation-name: …; instead of overwriting the other.

Hope my question is clear, thanks.

Comment: I believe the only way to go about this is to parse your CSS file, extract all the applicable animations for an element based on its classes, and then merge them dynamically.

Comment: The only way to achieve this is creating an inner div, and setting your second animation to the child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% satisfied, this does do the job.

I'm now using a small bit of jQuery.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $( '.btn' ).css( 'animation-name', function( index, value) {
        return $( this ).attr('class').replace( / /g, ',' );
    });
    $( '.btn' ).css( '-webkit-animation-name', function( index, value) {
        return $( this ).attr('class').replace( / /g, ',' );
    });

});`
```